# openVPN stops after some minutes of inactivity

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ssl

It's been months now that I'm looking for a solution. I've read the whole google...
It is very annoying specially on 2FA...

```
 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-down' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'vpn-down' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:2 'vpn-down' [tun1]: new request (1 scripts)
 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:3 'vpn-down' [tun2]: new request (1 scripts)
 laptop NetworkManager: vpn-connection["myVPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
 laptop NetworkManager: vpn-connection["myVPN",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

Comment: That first line of the log seems to indicate that you have a script somewhere which is requesting vpn to be disconnected, for some reason.

Comment: Hi, for sure is not my script... It is probably Ubuntu's and I would like to find it and change it. I don't see any option on network manager for time outs when in lock screen or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought.

[image]

The suspend mode was calling some scripts causing usb ports to close and therefore my dock station who was connected to them and ethernet on it was losing connection.

I disabled auto-suspend and also switched to wifi in order to completely avoid connectivity to dock and I found the VPNs working after two hours of inactivity on lock screen.